# Bash: Identify a Terminal Session

Tags: linux, bash, macos, session, terminal

I routinely use Bash on Linux (Centos) and Mac. Ultimately I plan on writing something to record a permanent history of my Bash commands, and I think I know how to do do that.

I often have more than one terminal session and so I often issue commands from the different sessions. This will, of course, make a mess of any history if the sessions commands are all interspersed.

The question is: **is there some sort of accessible session id or any other way I can identify which session originated a command?**

Comment: `TERM_SESSION_ID` -- however it is not always available. You could make sure that it is, however. In `~/.profile` or comparable, set it if it isn't already set. `[ -n "$TERM_SESSION_ID" ] || export TERM_SESSION_ID="$(uuidgen)"`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/80882/233622

Comment: @Jameson THANK YOU for pointing me down this path for using `TERM_SESSION_ID` as a unique identifier for a macOS terminal. Works great, at least on macOS.